# Zend not uploading files

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I am trying to upload files using zend but cant seem to figure why this piece of code won't work. It doesnt show up in the directory that I specified. Any help would be nice. Thanks!

```
public function uploadFormAction()
{
  $form     = new UploadForm('upload-form');
    $tempFile = null;

    $prg = $this->fileprg($form);
    if ($prg instanceof Response) {
        return $prg; // Return PRG redirect response
    } elseif (is_array($prg)) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

           // echo $data['image-file']['name'];

            $tmp = $data['image-file']['tmp_name'];
            $name = $data['image-file']['name'];
            $uploads_dir = '//Applications/MAMP/htdocs/';


             move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$uploads_dir");

             echo($name);
             echo($uploads_dir);



            // Form is valid, save the form!
           // return $this->redirect()->toRoute('uploadForm/success');
        } else {
            // Form not valid, but file uploads might be valid...
            // Get the temporary file information to show the user in the view
            $fileErrors = $form->get('image-file')->getMessages();
            if (empty($fileErrors)) {
                $tempFile = $form->get('image-file')->getValue();
            }
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form'     => $form,
        'tempFile' => $tempFile,
    );
}
```

HTML FORM - upload-form.html

```
 $title = 'Upload';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
 <?php
 $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'uploadForm')));
 $form->prepare();?>

 <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>

    <div class="form-element">
        <?php $fileElement = $form->get('image-file'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formLabel($fileElement); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formFile($fileElement); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($fileElement); ?>
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm gonna throw an obvious one out there, do you have the attribute <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> ??

Comment: yes I do i have that, I updated the question.  Its calling this function to display the page when user hits submit.

Comment: Have you tried checking if it actually succeeds to upload it somewhere with something like `if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$uploads_dir")) echo 'Succeeded'; else echo 'Failed';`? Just to see if it 1) gets to that part, 2) fails on the upload?

Answer (score 0):

it seams you have forgot to add `enctype` to your `<form>`

> $form->setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

Answer (score 0):

Its seems your destination directory path is not correct.

```
$uploads_dir = '//Applications/MAMP/htdocs/';
```

This Should be like:

```
$uploads_dir=realpath(APPLICATION_PATH) . "/../public/Your directory path
```

you can check your path with **is_dir** function.